Norton equivalent current source direction in this circut

I want to convert R1 and V1 to Norton. What will be the direction of the current source?
Edit: As mentioned in @RussellH comment, "the current must enter and exit the same nodes before and after the conversion" I transformed all the voltage sources:


Short the output and find out.

There is no quick way without calculations? Because when my professor used it he just replaced it with a current source, and no one asked how he knew the direction, he didn't even mention something about the direction.

Are you asking for the source transformation of R1,V1. Or the Norton equivalent of the circuit?

I thought that "the Norton equivalent of the R1 and V1 branch" is like saying source transformation. Thats how we call it. I know Norton can be on the whole circut too

The current must enter and exit the same nodes before and after the conversion. @amit. Just a note: use the "@"name to notify a user that a comment is available.

@amit You aren't, but assuming you are thoroughly familiar with transforming between Norton and Thevenin, then: (1) V1 & R1 --> Ix & Rx; and, (2) Iy replaces Ix+I1; and, (3) Ry replaces Rx||R3; and, (4) Iy & Ry --> Vz & Rz; and, (5) Va replaces Vz+V2 and Ra replaces Rz+R2; and, (6) Vb & Rb replaces Va & divider Ra&R4; and, (7) Vc replaces Vb+V3; and, (8) Vc and Rc replaces Vb & divider Rb&R5. There are some interesting special cases you may see as you proceed in the above analysis. But, no matter, it's all about Norton/Thevenin conversions back and forth. Why don't you know the direction?

@periblepsis Thanks for your help, but I got confused with the variables. I tried to solve it again in the edit.

@amit I added an answer to push you along a bit. I hope it helps some.

Okay. You got the direction right with \$R_1\$ and the current source to the left of it!!! This is great!
Let me suggest some help now:

I didn't take everything you did in your update. Just the \$V_1\$ and \$R_1\$ parts. Notice that the two current sources cancel out. And since they have \$\infty\$ impedance you can just cut them out from the circuit, as shown above.
Now you can see that \$R_1\$ and \$R_3\$ (as you show) are in parallel. And can be combined into a single resistor of \$25\:\Omega\$:

But now \$R_2\$ and the newly created \$25\:\Omega\$ resistor can be combined, as they are in series with each other. So that's the same as:

And at this point, this slight modification may help a little further:

You should now see a voltage divider presented to \$V_2\$. And you should be able to work out the Thevenin equivalent of those three parts, making them into a new voltage source and just one resistor (instead of two.) Then you can combine that with what remains.
Does this help you get closer?
I really enjoyed seeing your edited addition to your question. That's the kind of thing that tells me you will do well. I'm excited for you and proud to see you moving forward like this. +1 for the added work!

Thanks. Just to be sure, did I convert the other two voltage sources right?

@amit Yes, except that the rightmost conversion obscures important node a. (Changes it.) So it won't work out the right answer.
